# Randomize sorting in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I would like to know, is there is any way to do random sorting in XSLT 1.0?

Here is my XML

```
<root><DO status="a">text comes here</DO><DO status="b">text comes here</DO><DO status="c">text comes here</DO><DO status="d">text comes here</DO><DO status="e">text comes here</DO></root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<root><DO status="c">text</DO><DO status="a">text comes here</DO><DO status="b">text comes here</DO><DO status="e">text comes here</DO><DO status="d">text comes here</DO></root>
```

Hope my question is clear?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know, is there is any way to do random sorting in XSLT 1.0?

With vanilla XSLT 1.0 - No.

You could use an extension to access the randomizer of an external language and put that function into `xsl:sort`. For example, using the `msxsl` extension to access Windows Scripting languages:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:my="http://tempuri.org/myscripts" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my"
>

  <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="my">
    function random() {
      return Math.random();
    }
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="DO">
      <xsl:sort select="my:random()" data-type="number" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just checked and this also works fine with [exslt’s math functions](http://exslt.org/math/index.html), (f. e. available in libXML) like this: `<xsl:sort select="math:random()" data-type="number" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XSLT `generate-id()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id) which returns a string that uniquely identifies a node in the document. In accordance with specification:

> An implementation is free to generate
>   an identifier in any convenient way
>   provided that it always generates the
>   same identifier for the same node and
>   that different identifiers are always
>   generated from different nodes. An
>   implementation is under no obligation
>   to generate the same identifiers each
>   time a document is transformed. There
>   is no guarantee that a generated
>   unique identifier will be distinct
>   from any unique IDs specified in the
>   source document.

So it depends on your XSLT processor.